# Problems while trying to get specific items and format them with selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am crawling a [website](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/drugshortages/default.cfm) which has some tables. Specifically, I would like to extract from all the tables (if exist), the first column (`presentation`) and the `company name` (which is located in this xpath: `.//*[@id='accordion']//h3`), something like this (a two dimension format):

```
['Mission Pharmacal (Reverified 01/21/2015)' , '250 mg (NDC 01780-500-01)']
['Hospira, Inc. (Reverified 11/07/2016)', '5 mEq/mL; 20 mL vial (NDC 0409-6043-01)']
['Shire US Inc. (Reverified 07/01/2016)', 'AGRYLIN® (anagrelide hydrochloride) Dosage Form: 0.5 mg capsules for oral administration (NDC 54092-063-01)']
['Teva Pharmaceuticals (Reverified 11/01/2016)', '1mg 100 (NDC 00172-5240-60)']
['Teva Pharmaceuticals (Reverified 11/01/2016)', '0.5 mg 10 (NDC 00172-5241-60)']
['Jazz Pharmaceuticals, Inc. (Revised 11/14/2016)', 'ERWINAZE 10,000 IU lyophilized powder supplied in a clear 3 mL glass vial 5 vial carton (NDC 57902-249-05)']
[' Jazz Pharmaceuticals, Inc. (Revised 11/14/2016)', 'ERWINAZE 10,000 IU lyophilized powder supplied in a clear 3 mL glass vial 1 vial (NDC 57902-249-01)']
```

So far I tried the below approach. However, I do not get how to tweak the list, and I do not understand why I am not catching some hidden items, from the accordion.

In:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/drugshortages/default.cfm')
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('''.//*[@id='tabs-1']//tbody//td[1]//a[2]''')
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in links]

lis = list()
for x in links:    
    driver.get(x)    
    #.//*[@id='accordion']//div//table

    xpath_list = ['.//*[@id="accordion"]//div//tr//td[1]', ".//*[@id='accordion']//h3//a"]
    full_content = [[x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)] for xpath in xpath_list]
    lis.append(full_content)

lis
```

Out:

```
[[['250 mg (NDC 01780-500-01)'], []],
 [['5 mEq/mL; 20 mL vial (NDC 0409-6043-01)'], []],
 [['AGRYLIN® (anagrelide hydrochloride) Dosage Form: 0.5 mg capsules for oral administration (NDC 54092-063-01)',
   '',
   ''],
  ['Shire US Inc. (Reverified 07/01/2016)',
   'Teva Pharmaceuticals (Reverified 11/01/2016)']],
 [['ERWINAZE 10,000 IU lyophilized powder supplied in a clear 3 mL glass vial 5 vial carton (NDC 57902-249-05)',
   'ERWINAZE 10,000 IU lyophilized powder supplied in a clear 3 mL glass vial 1 vial (NDC 57902-249-01)'],
  ['Jazz Pharmaceuticals, Inc. (Revised 11/14/2016)']],
 [['0.4 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 25 (NDC 00517-0401-25)',
   '1 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 25 (NDC 00517-1010-25)',
   '',
   '',
   '',
   '',
   '',
   ''],......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

r = requests.get('http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/drugshortages/dsp_ActiveIngredientDetails.cfm?AI=Atropine%20Sulfate%20Injection&st=c&tab=tabs-1')
html = fromstring(r.text)
```

in:

```
[i.text_content().strip() for i in html.xpath('//div[@id="accordion"]//h3')]
```

out:

```
['American Regent/Luitpold (Reverified 11/10/2016)',
 'Amphastar Pharmaceuticals, Inc./IMS (Reverified 08/18/2016)',
 'Hospira, Inc. (Revised 11/07/2016)',
 'West-Ward Pharmaceuticals (Revised 05/02/2016)']
```

in:

```
[i.xpath('.//td[1]//text()') for i in html.xpath('//div[@id="accordion"]//tbody')]
```

out:

```
[['0.4 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 25\r\n(NDC 00517-0401-25)',
  '1 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 25 (NDC 00517-1010-25)'],
 ['0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Luer-Jet Prefilled Syringe\r\n(NDC 76329-3339-1, Old NDC 0548-3339-00) \r\n'],
 ['0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Ansyr syringe\r\n(NDC 0409-1630-10)',
  '0.05 mg/mL; 5 mL Ansyr syringe\r\n(NDC 0409-9630-05)',
  '0.1 mg/mL; 5 mL Lifeshield syringe\r\n(NDC 0409-4910-34)',
  '0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Lifeshield syringe\r\n(NDC 0409-4911-34)'],
 ['0.4 mg/mL, 20 mL vial (NDC 0641-6006-10)\r\n']]
```

i ues lxml's xpath, i hope this will be helpful. By the way, nested list comprehension is really hard to understand., maybe you could create lists separately, than zip them toganther.

Comment: Thanks for the help!. The thing is that I am interested in iterate over the content of each link in the website (not the page that you provided). Particularly in getting the first column of each table and the company name which is located in the accordion, not in getting the index that you provided.

Comment: I updated the question with more details, thanks for the help!